# How to add attachment in to the bugzilla using java prgramming language?

Tags: java, bugzilla

I want to attach a screenshot to the bug in Bugzilla via code. I am using J2Bugzilla API but unable to find the required method. Please suggest if any other API for attaching a file in Bugzilla using Java.

Comment: Have you found solution and can you share ?


I am using a python module for interacting with Bugzilla over XMLRPC
https://git.fedorahosted.org/git/python-bugzilla.git
My Bugzilla version is 4.2.3

By using add_attachment method I can upload files with different extensions (.zip, .jpg etc) , but uploaded files got corrupted. So, I am not sure if this Bugzilla Attachment API is stable or not..

Answer (score 0):

To attach any file with J2Bugzilla, you must first create an `Attachment`:

```
byte[] data = ...;//Read the data as a byte array from the image file

AttachmentFactory attachmentFactory = new AttachmentFactory();
Attachment attachment = attachmentFactory.newAttachment()
    .setData(data)
    .setMime("...")//Set the appropriate MIME type for the image format
    .setSummary("My screenshot")
    .createAttachment();
```

Then, you can add it to an existing bug report using `AddAttachment`:

```
AddAttachment add = new AddAttachment(attachment, bug);
//'bug' is a Bug you have previously retrieved
//'conn' is the BugzillaConnector
conn.executeMethod(add);
```

Comment: No, it will not, as the [WebService docs](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.6/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/Bug.html) indicate. However, this could be better explained in the API documentation.